# how we can edit stored procedure in sql*plus so that i can correct it

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
create or replace procedure minvalue(x in number,y in number,z in number)
 as
begin
  if x< y then
   z := x;
 else
  z:= y;
end if;
end;
/
compilation error.
```

in this code, x and y are parameters which takes values when user run this procedure and z take out the answer . this code find minimum values between x and y ,and store minimum value through z.

I created this procedure on sql>. now how I can put this in buffer again. so that i can modify /enhance it. But I don't know how to open this procedure through sql command. Pls help me.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL*Plus the `ed` command will open your last statement in the default editor (unless you've defined something else in your `login.sql` script).

It's good practice to write code as scripts in a decent text editor or IDE and run those scripts at the SQL*Plus command line.

So, the actual error is this:

```
create or replace minvalue
```

That should be `create or replace procedure minvalue`.  Once you clear the `ORA-00922` missing or invalid option exception the next issue is:

```
   c := x;
```

You haven't declared a variable `c` so this will hurl an `ORA-00904` invalid identifier exception.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to execute your statement again, it does as it says `create or replace` the stored procedure.

If you want to know which errors occured, enter `show errors` after executing.

PS: You dont't use Parameter `z`so why is it there? You'll need a function with a return value not a procedure if you want to return something.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile the PL/SQL code.
2. Use `SHOW ERROR` to validate.
3. If you see any compilation errors, use `ed` to modify the code.
4. Save the `afiedt.buf` file.
5. You will see the modified code loaded, just use `/` to recompile the code.

For example,

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2     NULL;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SHOW ERROR
No errors.
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  BEGIN
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.pUT_LINE('code modified');
  3* END;
SQL> /
code modified

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```